# Forwarding within local network to same network

Tags: networking, routes, iptables, openwrt

I have X-Wrt based on OpenWrt 8.09 on my router

I have home LAN of few computers on which I have some network servers (SVN, web, etc). For each of service I made forwarding on my router (Linksys wrt54gl) to access it from the Internet (`<my_external_ip>:<external_port> -> <some_internal_ip>:<internal_port>`)

But within my local network this resources by above request is unreachable (so I need make some reconfiguration `<some_internal_ip>:<internal_port>` to access).

I added some line to my /etc/hosts
`<my_external_ip>  localhost`

So now all requests from local network to `<my_external_ip>` forwards to my router but further redirection to appropriate port not works.

Advise proper redirection please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install an IP redirect for calls going out of the internal network and directed to the public IP. Normally these packets get discarded. You want to reroute them, DNATting to the destination server, but also masqueraded so that the server, seeing as you, its client, are in its same network, doesn't respond directly to you with its internal IP (which you, the client, not having sent the packet there, would discard).

I found this on OpenWRT groups:

```
iptables -t nat -A prerouting_rule -d YOURPUBLICIP -p tcp --dport PORT -j DNAT --to YOURSERVER
iptables -A forwarding_rule -p tcp --dport PORT -d YOURSERVER -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A postrouting_rule -s YOURNETWORK -p tcp --dport PORT -d YOURSERVER -j MASQUERADE
```

https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?id=4030

Comment: Guys @`Kuba Wyrostek` and `lserni` your both answers is great and I'm totally confused. I gave bounty to Kuba Wyrostek but in a minute answer of lserni has been placed. I'm using lserni's method. lserni, I marked answer as accepted i don't know what to do more.

Comment: That's absolutely okay, the important thing is that things are working. Don't worry, I'm new here too :-D

Comment: I feel embarassed though. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly OpenWrt allows you to define custom DNS entries. So maybe simply give a proper local names to your sources (ie. svnserver.local) and map them to specific local IPs. This way you do not even need to go through router to access local resources from local network.

Comment: I have few services on one machine behind my router. And I need the same address-line to access from LAN and from Internet. Can you clarify with an example your proposal?

Comment: Yes. I.e. if you external IP can be resolved from my-home.dyndns.org then overwrite it in OpenWrt: make static DNS entry that resolves svnserver.my-home.dyndns.org to your local IP. Do the same for other services (ie. webserver.my-home.dyndns.org). Meanwhile configure external DNS so that requests to *.my-home.dyndns.org (notice *) resolves to your external ip. This way you can use the same name with different IP adresses depending on which network you are calling DNS from. I was using this scenario sucessfully to access SVN repository from both home and office with the same repository URL.

Comment: how about port forwarding, should i use same external and internal ports?

Comment: in this scenario - yes. otherwise the urls would differ. please note that internal traffic does not go through router though then.

Comment: Ok I see. One problem I not use external hostname but access by IP. Indeed there is no way solve it on routing side?

Comment: I am afraid I don't know of any. Please wait for other answers then. I decided to propose using names as binding a domain to your IP is quite cheap these days and this is more general and usable solution. :-)

Comment: and i need my own DNS-server on the router?